Stalling of Multiprocessing in Python
I experience a strange behavior of the multiprocessing module. Can anyone explain what is going on here?
The following MWE stalls (runs forever without error):
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import multiprocessing

import numpy as np
from skimage import io
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

def create_model():
    sampled_pixels = np.random.randint(0, 255, (800,3))
    kmeans_model = KMeans(n_clusters=8, random_state=0).fit(sampled_pixels)

def process_image(test, test2):
    image  = np.random.randint(0, 255, (800,3))
    kmeans_model = KMeans(n_clusters=8, random_state=0).fit(image)
    image = kmeans_model.predict(image)

def main():

    create_model()

    with multiprocessing.Pool(1) as pool:

        pool.apply_async(process_image, args=('test', 'test'))

        pool.close()
        pool.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

However, if I either remove the line create_model() OR change
def process_image(test, test2)
# as well as
pool.apply_async(process_image, args=('test', 'test'))

to
def process_image(test)`
# and
pool.apply_async(process_image, args=('test'))

the code runs successfully, as it should, since the arguments as well as the function call create_model() are completely redundant.

Appendix
> pip list
Package       Version
------------- ---------
imageio       2.34.0
joblib        1.4.0
lazy_loader   0.4
networkx      3.3
numpy         1.26.4
packaging     24.0
pillow        10.3.0
pip           23.2.1
scikit-image  0.23.1
scikit-learn  1.4.2
scipy         1.13.0
threadpoolctl 3.4.0
tifffile      2024.2.12

> python --version
Python 3.12.2


args=('test')) .... that's a typo, tuples of one element need a comma otherwise the parenthesis are ignored args=('test',)) ... probably unrelated

I think I tracked it down to a bug / shortcoming in GNU OpenMP. In short, GNU OpenMP used by scikit-learn is not fork-safe:

If your program intends to become a background process [...], you must not use the OpenMP features before the fork. After OpenMP features are utilized, a fork is only allowed if the child process does not use OpenMP features, or it does so as a completely new process (such as after exec()).

A minimal way to trigger this is:
import multiprocessing
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

def kmeans():
    KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0).fit([[1, 1], [2, 2]])

kmeans()
with multiprocessing.Pool(1) as pool:
    pool.apply_async(kmeans)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

For possible mitigations, see this link.
